# Pear Mail sends email without attachment

Tags: php, email, sendmail, pear

I am trying to send mail using  `PHP PEAR Mail` with some attached files. I am reading a text file to get the `filenames` and then using this to create a `filePath` from which I can attach the file as per the PEAR `addAttachment()` syntax. But when I receive the mail it has no attachments.

**My code**

```
function sendMail() {
    $pdf_filename = file_get_contents("/tmp/uploads/filelog/pdfFiles.txt");
    $csv_filename = file_get_contents("/tmp/uploads/filelog/csvFiles.txt");

    $text = 'Text version of email';
    $html = '<html><body>HTML version of email</body></html>';
    $csv_file = '/tmp/uploads/csv/' . $csv_filename;
    $pdf_file = '/tmp/uploads/pdf/' . $pdf_filename;
    $crlf = "\n";
    $hdrs = array (
            'From' => 'you@yourdomain.com',
            'Subject' => 'Test mime message' 
    );

    $mime = new Mail_mime ( array (
            'eol' => $crlf 
    ) );
    $mime->setTXTBody ( $text );
    $mime->setHTMLBody ( $html );
    $mime->addAttachment ( $csv_file, 'text/csv' );
    $mime->addAttachment ( $pdf_file, 'application/pdf' );
    $body = $mime->get ();
    $hdrs = $mime->headers ( $hdrs );
    $mail = & Mail::factory ( 'mail' );
    $mail->send ( 'user@sippycup.co.uk', $hdrs, $body );
    if (PEAR::isError ( $mail )) {
        echo ("<p>" . $mail->getMessage () . "</p>");
    } else {
         echo ("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    }
}
sendMail();
```

Why is this not working? Even though I have confirmed that both files exist on the server.

Comment: The `file_get_contents()` don't make any sense. You're not getting the name of the file, you're getting a string with all the content. So then when you make `$csv_file = '/tmp/uploads/csv/' . $csv_filename;` that would not be a file path.

Comment: @Twisty I am getting contents from text files which have the filenames for my pdf and csv files. The string is the filename!

Comment: 1 file name? 5 file names? 20? You will get all the content of the file. Post an example of the text file.

Comment: @Twisty one filename from each textfile I have verified the path with echo it's a valid path!

Comment: Seems like a lot of work for a filename, but I think I get it. The rest looks textbook from the example. `addAttachment()` does throw an error, so you can do a try/catch when you attach and see if an error is thrown: `if (PEAR::isError ( $mime )){`

Comment: @Twisty Ye I was storing the filenames using sessions and that worked fine I decided to change that and use this instead and it doesn't work even though the echoed paths are identical very strange. Will try your suggestion when I get the chance.

Comment: I see no benefit to storing them in a file versus session. I would have stored them in a DB if I needed them to live longer.

Comment: @Twisty The benefits might not be clear with the little that i've posted but this is the route i'm forced to take. `if (PEAR::isError ( $mime )){` caught nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some whitespaces being generated, a simple `trim()` fixed my problem.

```
$csv_trimed = trim($csv_file);
$pdf_trimed = trim($pdf_file);
.
.
.
.
.

$mime->addAttachment ( $csv_trimed, 'text/csv' );
$mime->addAttachment ( $pdf_trimed, 'application/pdf' );
```